# Property of $L^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

the following property of  functions in ${L^1{\mathbb{(R^N)}}}$ appears in my book of functional analysis without proof and I don't get prove it:

If $f\in{L^1{(\mathbb{R^N})}}$ then $\lim_{k \to{+}\infty}{\displaystyle\int_{|z|>k}|f(z)|}=0$

Could someone help me with it?
Thanks.

Comment: Dominated convergence.

Comment: That holds for $L^p$ for $p\ge1$ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find the domain of integration changing with the variable, you can use indicator functions  to make the domain of integration uniform. This allows us to then use the convergence theorems we know.

In this case, $\int_{|z| > k} |f(z)| d \mu = \int_{\mathbb R^N} 1_{\{|z| > k\}} |f(z)| d\mu$. Now, let $g_k(z) = 1_{\{|z| > k\}} |f(z)|$.

- Where does $g_k(z)$ converge pointwise as $k  \to \infty$?
- Is $g_k$ uniformly bounded by some integrable function? $f$ is given to be integrable : that should help.
- The dominated convergence theorem completes the argument.

A comment says above that this holds for $L^p, p \geq 1$ as well. You can see if an argument similar to the above works out.

Comment: Thanks. I have learnt a new trick for these exercises

Comment: You are welcome! This is a very common trick.

Comment: Excuse me. I am also stucked in this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3028717/484724 . Can you help me please? I have been trying it for several days,but I don't get solve it.  Thanks.